# Mist Wallet - I Messed Up

Tags: mist, testnets, cpp-ethereum

I sent almost 3 ETH from my Bitfinex account to a wallet on Mist. I had just downloaded Mist and was not familiar with the Addresses.... I accidentally sent this ETH to my Mist wallet on the Rinkeby Test net. Is there any way to get this back? It has not appeared in my Testnet wallet balance. Please laugh and advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a wallet uses the same private key encoding/encryption to wallet address, therefore your Rinkeby wallet address is also a wallet in mainnet.  So if you sent ether to that address, you should have received it in mainnet.  Check etherscan.io for that address and you should be able to see your Ether in that same wallet address.
To access that ether, just use the same private key to unlock that wallet on mainnet.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give this a try. I appreciate the straightforward answer!

Comment: So I have been kind of busy and didn't get to try this out until just recently. I am not sure if it is simply just a problem with my Mist Ethereum Wallet not being synced or if there is something else going on. Here is the link to the transaction https://etherscan.io/address/0x36d64A637616B60A9EF519B0f836E2042e3C0Cd4 When I search this Tx hash on the Rinkeby Etherscan though it tell me the transaction cannot be found. If my mist wallet is synced up, where would these 2.92 ether be? My adresses for the rinkeby test net wallet (main) and main net wallet are different. All help is appreciated!